# Java project showed as Folder instead Module in Intelliji

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a root directory on where I'm creating my projects. The point is that im allways creating a new project from the top menu bar and i want to create the broject by right click on the sidebar.

Also, on the sidebar i cannot see my actual projects as Project/Module, i see them as simple folders and cannot even create JavaClass for them.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cTyT.png)

Do you know why this happens ?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Labsx.png)

I'm creating my projects and working only with that one project on sidebar but i want to see the full root directory and work from there being able to see al my project folders as actual projects.

Comment: You likely added content roots to the existing module instead of configuring it as a separate module. Consider adding a new module instead. If you need a better answer, post a sample project on GitHub.